# Using twitter streaming API in wpf app

Tags: wpf, windows, .net-4.0, twitter

I want to use twitter streaming API in my WPF application, I am able to complete authentication process using OAuth. My problem is I am not aware of the process of fetching tweets from twitter. Can anyone provide me some sample application which can help me understand the proces of fetching and updating tweets.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at a library such as [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net)? It would probably make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from the Twitter stream is pretty easy. You just make a request, get the response stream, and start reading. For example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(twitter_search_url);
// this uses password authentication. Change for OAuth
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(TwitterUser, TwitterPassword);
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.UserAgent = user_agent_string;
HttpWebResponse response;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // line contains the tweet.
        // parse with a JSON reader
    }
    // end of stream
 }
 catch (... handle exceptions here)
 {
 }
 finally
 {
     response.Close();
 }
```

The response stream is essentially infinite, so you'll be stuck in that `ReadLine` loop forever.

I've been using a slightly more complete version of the above code for a couple of years without trouble. The production code has better error handling, of course, and the loop checks a `Shutdown` event so I can exit it cleanly, but the mechanics of reading the Twitter stream are identical.

Comment: Jim, Thanks for reply, but i am getting the same problem warned by you. I am stuck in an infinite loop, and not able to get a way to resolve this problem. Can you help me further on how can I read data from this infinite stream.

Comment: @Vibhore: When I say "infinite loop", I mean that data just keeps coming. It never stops. I don't have trouble at all reading the stream. The code above doesn't have any means to *stop* reading the stream, but that can be easily added. What, exactly, is the problem you're having.

Comment: Jim, I need to read all data from this stream to have most recent tweets. But problem is I am not able to read all of data from stream as it throws an InvalidOperationException. I am trying to use Stream.ReadToEnd().

Comment: @Vibhore: There's no way `Stream.ReadToEnd` is going to give you all the data. At best it's going to read two gigabytes of stuff and then throw an exception. *There is no end* to the Twitter stream. You have to read it a line at a time, or perhaps a block at a time.

Comment: Jim, That doesn't solve my problem, if I read data line by line it will be real slow process, I need to have at most 100 recent tweets, but if read the stream sequentially I don't get recent tweets, also I can't perform seek on this stream. Is there any way to get most recent tweets.

Comment: @Vibhore: You get the 100 most recent tweets by reading 100 lines from the stream. But perhaps you don't need the streaming API. Maybe you want the twitter search api instead? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search